# Data not persisted when updating rows with Eloquent

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update a table in an SQL Server database using the Eloquent ORM, but for some reason the update is never committed. As it is a legacy database I have defined my model in the following fashion (as the table and the key do not fully adhere to the expected conventions and the timestamp columns are not named updated_at, created_at)

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static $key  = 'UserID';
    public static $table = 'User';
    public static $timestamps = false;
}
```

The code I'm trying to run is as simple as this:

```
    $user = User::find($userid);
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->salt = $salt;
    $user->resettoken = $reset_token;
    $user->save();
```

I've debugged the code and can see that the User object is retrieved properly and the attributes of the User object are updated when assigned with new values. However, the save method doesn't persist the data.

Using Fluent works like treat, though.  This works for example:

```
$affected = DB::table('User')
                ->where('UserID', '=', $userid)
                ->update(array(
                    'password' => $password, 
                    'salt' => $salt, 
                    'resettoken' => $reset_token
                )
            );
```

But it would be nice to use Eloquent. What's tripping me?

**UPDATE:** Running the code as Pierre said:

```
<?php
$test = new User();
die(var_dump($test));
```

Returns:

```
object(User)[39]
  public 'attributes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'original' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'relationships' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'exists' => boolean false
  public 'includes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

The dump of the instance of the User object shows all the attributes, ie this object contains all attributes including the new values, but nothing is saved to database:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
$user->password = $password;
$user->salt = $salt;
$user->resettoken = $reset_token;
$user->save();
```

Using this syntax makes no difference:

```
$user = User::where_UserID($userid)->first();
```

**Solution:**

One has to use a lower case name of the key in the model, then it works.

Comment: There has to be an error message or log entry, please post that too.

Comment: @dualed - There is no error message whatsoever when using the Eloquent update syntax. It just passes silently. I have step debugged the code and I can see how the attributes are populated. In the save method of the model class, $result is always 0. Even if I set $result to 1 nothing is persisted to db.

Comment: The save method will always run a query unless it is not *dirty*. Since you say you have step-debugged it I assume it passes that point. So there is either a PHP error or an SQL error at some point. Since you say there is no error message, the logical conclusion is that there must be a log entry.

Comment: @dualed - Thanks for your input. I've set display_errors to true in php.ini, nothing pops out. In the profiler bar there are two queries run: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [User] WHERE [UserID] = '162'` and `UPDATE [User] SET [password] = 'password', [salt] = 'salt' WHERE [UserID] = ''` Notice the empty UserId value in the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use lower case name of the key name in your model.

This is wrong:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static $key  = 'UserID';
}
```

This works as expected:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static $key  = 'userid';
}
```

Comment: for information, now fixed on laravel 4 by [msvrtan](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/fd8881bb4446ee621bd4321a92b1d1ed8fa70262)

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent update looks like good. May your $key no work properly:

```
public static $key  = 'UserID';
```

What, is the version of your Laravel core ? I know some users repport this with previous version.

---

**Edit:**
[Quality Team about it...](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=4122)

You can verify this using:

```
<?php
$test = new User();
die(var_dump($test));
```

Used primary key will me mentioned (laravel 4 only)

For end, try :

```
$user = User::where_UserID($userid)->first();
$user->password = $password;
$user->salt = $salt;
$user->resettoken = $reset_token;
$user->save();
```

Comment: you were right, the key was defined in mixed case, just as the key name in the database. However, one has to use a lower case name, else it won't work. +1 for your effort.